# Перевод файлов HTML в ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

От дизайнера я получаю файлы HTML. Потом надо все это переписывать в ASP.NET MVC2, что делать, конечно, лень.

Есть ли готовое расширение для DreamWeaver, которое могло бы облегчить данный процесс? Ну или может быть не для DreamWeaver, а что-то похожее?

Comment: А что там так много надо кода переписывать????? И что там переводить надо????

Извините ,я может чего не понимаю.... Но там надо только составить мастер страницу и далее все по въюхам раскидать....Или я не прав????

Answer (score 1):

masterpages вам в помощь ну и web-developer express